# android is it possible to get notified when a new image,video is inserted,deleted from sd?

Tags: android

is it possible to get notified every time a new image,video is inserted on the sd card of your android device and how? I have looked at the Media Scanner class which indexes files but I can't find how to do get notified from that only how to notify Media Scanner of a new image I have created.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering a `ContentObserver` on the `MediaStore` content provider using a `ContentResolver`.